# Migration from Joomla 3 on an old OS (Debian 7) to Debian 10 : find a way to backup Mysql database with JSN pixel plugin

Tags: php, mysql, debian, joomla3.0, joomla-extensions

I have been searching a simple way to inject my MySQL database of previous Joomla 3 that I had on my Debian 7 on a new Debian 10. This file has been generated with a :

`mysqldump -u root -p --all-databases > alldb.txt`

In this file `alldb.txt`, there is the database called `joomla` where there is all the content of my website.

Now, I would like to make work this previous Joomla's website on a Debian Buster freshly installed.

**1)** In a first time, I tried a brutal method consisting to only copy all the arborescency of Debian 7 directory (`/var/www/website/`) to  the new directory of Debian 10 : this was achieved by :

`cp -rpf /var/www/website/* root@server:/var/www/newwebsite/`

But once all copied, the old content can't be displayed (when I go on `http://newserver/index.php`, nothing happens except the suggestion to download the file `index.php` : So I conclude that just copying the arborescency can't make work my original Joomla 3 CMS since I don't perform a real installation of Joomla 3.

**2)** So, I decided to do this installation of Joomla 3 on the `newserver` (OS Debian 10) by untar in `/var/www/newwebsite/` the archive `Joomla_3.2.1-Stable-Full_Package_French_v2.zip`.

The installation goes fine, I choose `mysql` instead of `mysqli` since originally, the mysqldump backup was done with MySQL database.

**3)** But first problem : at the final stage of installation, one asks me to indicate the type of website it is and I am obliged to give an answer (between `simple blog, native multi-language website, website to learn Joomla in French or English etc ...`). This choice will determinate the first page of my website : but this is not the page that I want, I want the pages of previous Joomla 3 website.

**4)** So, I thought that, by injecting all the database `joomla` into my database MySQL of Debian 10, I would get back all the content of previous Joomla. But the second problem is that I was using a plugin in this previous version, called "**JSN pixel**" (or **JSN pro pixel**").

I don't know how to manage this extension with new Joomla 3 of my Debian 10. I can't find the zip file or archive to upload on the personal webspace of Joomla  3 (I think it should exist a free version). So how can I circumvent this issue ? Anyone could know this extension : this is mostly used to display nicely a lot of images with icons and a slider.

I say that since I guess my big backup of previous MySQL ( I recall, the file `alldb.txt` above generated with `mysqldump) contains some fields of this`JSN pixel`extension, doesn't it ?

I want to reinstall Joomla 3 on my new Debian 10, but without indicate the type of website I want to put and with injecting correctly the database `joomla` into this new Joomla installation.

I tried do to simply : `$ mysql -u user -p joomla < alldb.txt`

It works fine but there seems to be conflicts between my Joomla 3 installation and the MySQL Database.: the original homepage is not the one expected (homepage of original website).

Surely the issue comes from this `JSN pixel` extension.

How can I recover all the old content from Joomla 3 (Debian 7) to clone it on Debian 10 with a classic setup of the same version of Joomla 3 on Debian 10 ?

Comment: I suggest starting just `mysqldump` the joomla database and not all of them. You probably have different mysql versions between the two and `--all-databases` includes system tables which may not be compatible. You'll need to recreate the joomla database user however.

Comment: I have already done this by executing : `mysql -u user -p --one-database joomla < alldb.txt` and database user is the same as before. My issue is rather to know if a simple copy is enough (with correct joomla database : you mean that I have to create again another user database) ? Regards